# Is there a way to increase form section header text size when device text size increases?

Tags: swiftui

I have a default form with a section that has a header. When I increase the device font size to accessibility extra large, text in the sections rows increase but the header doesn't. How can I make it also increase?

[Header text doesn't change size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2ELC.png)

Comment: You can set the font size to a var that is automatically scaled: `@ScaledMetric var headerSize: CGFloat = 20`

Comment: how do you set the font size of the header